# initializing member variable 2D vector in constructor

Tags: c++, vector, constructor, stdvector

I have a member variable two-dimensional vector in a class, like this:

```
#include <vector>
...
class MyClass {
private:
    int vector_size;
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > vector_2d;
public:
    MyClass(int _vector_size);
    ~MyClass();
} // class MyClass
```

I want to know the best way of implementing the constructor `MyClass(int _vector_size)` to fully initialize the vector to consist of `_vector_size` empty vectors. The code I have now is as follows (and this works perfectly fine in a little toy program I wrote to test correctness), but I feel like the declaration of `temp_vec` and the constant `temp_vec.clear()` might be a little redundant.

```
MyClass::MyClass(int _vector_size):
vector_size(_vector_size)
{
    // initialize vector_2d
    vector_2d.clear();
    // push initialized 1D vectors
    for (int i = 0; i < vector_size; ++i) {
        std::vector<int> temp_vec;
        temp_vec.clear();
        vector_2d.push_back(temp_vec);
    }
}
```

I have also checked other posts such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11350112/initializing-2d-vector-as-class-variable-c), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20460442/initialize-member-vector-in-constructor-c), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12794397/initializing-a-member-variable-stl-vector-through-a-class-constructor), but I think my question differs in that I want a *vector of specified size* that consists of *vectors of unspecified size*.

Comment: Sidenote: Clearing an already empty vector has no effect. It does _not_ initialize the vector. This is done in the constructor which is invoked automatically.

Comment: vectors store their size internally (which you can get using the `.size()` method), so storing the size separately in your class is at best redundant, and potentially buggy. Just query the vector when you want to know it's size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) have a [constructor overload](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) which takes a size for the vector.

You can use this to initialize your vector:

```
MyClass::MyClass(int size)
    : vector_size(size),
      vector_2d(size)
{
}
```

This will initialize `vector_2d` to have `size` elements. Each element is a default-constructed `std::vector<int>` object (the type of each element).

Comment: Thanks! one more question - What I was doing is definitely redundant but functionally correct, right?

Comment: @WannabeArchitect It's not wrong at least. :) But you don't need the `clear` calls, vectors are default-constructed as empty.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, `vector_2d` is default-initialzied as empty `std::vector` firstly (thus calling of `clear()` is superfluous), then gets modified in the body of constructor.

You can initialize it directly in member initializer list. E.g.

```
// initializa vector_2d as containing _vector_size empty std::vector<int>
MyClass::MyClass(int _vector_size):
vector_size(_vector_size), vector_2d(_vector_size) {}
```